# Class receiving the value reset

Tags: asp.net, .net, class, asp.net-core

I'm doing insert via post, but my class is getting the zero values of the inputs.

The values of the inputs are passed via variable and corrections are displayed, but at the time of the post are coming down.

The most interesting thing is if you type inside the input, then the values come correctly.

```
 <form method="post">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>SALDO</label>
            <div style="border:1px solid #bbb9b9; border-radius:3px;"></div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalDinheiro" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalDinheiro" name="Caixas.ValorFinalDinheiro"  id="Caixas.ValorFinalDinheiro" class="form-control finalFundo"  disabled="disabled" />

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalCheque" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalCheque" class="form-control finalFundo"  disabled="disabled"/>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalBoleto" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalBoleto" class="form-control finalFundo"  disabled="disabled" />

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalCartao" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalCartao" class="form-control finalFundo"  disabled="disabled" />

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalDeposito" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalDeposito" class="form-control finalFundo" disabled="disabled"  />

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinal" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinal" class="form-control" style="background-color:#9FF781"   />

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Confirmar o Fechamento do Caixa" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  />
                <a asp-page="Index" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Retorna ao Caixa</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>




  [BindProperty]
        public Caixas Caixas { get; set; }



        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {


            var C = _context.Caixas.Find(Caixas.Id);
            C.fechado = true;
            C.DataFinal = DateTime.Now;
            C.HoraFinal = DateTime.Now;
            C.FuncionarioFechamentoId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
            C.ValorFinalDinheiro = Caixas.ValorFinalDinheiro;
            C.ValorFinalCheque = Caixas.ValorFinalCheque;
            C.ValorFinalBoleto = Caixas.ValorFinalBoleto;
            C.ValorFinalCartao = Caixas.ValorFinalCartao;
            C.ValorFinalDeposito = Caixas.ValorFinalDeposito;
            C.ValorFinal = Caixas.ValorFinal;

            C.ValorSaida = Caixas.ValorSaida;


            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Caixas property and add it as parameter in your OnPostAsync method:

```
// [BindProperty]
// public Caixas Caixas { get; set; }

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync([FromBody]Caixas c)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Doing this way I'm getting null value